# Reducing every image in collection using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, reducers

I want to reduce every single image in a collection, but I have not been able to make it. The process is really easy and works with a single image, but I need to do the same for every image in the collection.

My code:

```
// Statistics function
var stats = function(img) {
            var image = ee.Image(img);
            var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
                reducer2: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
                sharedInputs: true
                });
            var stats = image.reduceRegion({
                reducer: reducers,
                //geometry: geometry(),
                bestEffort: true,
                });
            return stats;
}

//Load collection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');

// Extract the image index from collection and make a list
var index = ee.List(['20190101T160509_20190101T160509_T17RNJ',
                    '20190104T160649_20190104T161509_T17RLH',
                    '20190104T160649_20190104T161509_T17RMJ',
                    '20190104T160649_20190104T161509_T17RMK']);

// Filter collection by image id list
var coll = collection
          .filter(ee.Filter.inList('system:index',index));
```

The reducer works perfectly for a single image

```
// Apply the statistics function over the whole extent of a single image
var one_stats = stats(coll.first());
print('One Stats',one_stats)
```

But, it does not work properly for every image in a collection

```
// Apply the statistics function over the whole extent of every image
var all_stats = coll.map(stats);
print('All Stats',all_stats)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is:

```
Collection.map: A mapped algorithm must return a Feature or Image.
```

This tells you what the problem is: you have to return a Feature or Image, but you have returned a Dictionary instead. A convenient solution in this case is to just make the contents of the dictionary be properties of the image: instead of `return stats;`, do

```
return image.setMulti(stats);
```

But you can also choose to return a newly created `Feature` that has only the properties you want and nothing of the original image.

By the way, you might want to `select` the bands you're interested in before the `reduceRegion` so that you're not computing statistics for bands you're not interested in.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to return a feature or Image. Currently, you return a dictionary from the function. Set the output for example as properties to each image:

```
// Statistics function
var getStats = function(img) {
            var image = ee.Image(img);
            var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
                reducer2: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
                sharedInputs: true
                });
            var stats = image.reduceRegion({
                reducer: reducers,
                //geometry: geometry(),
                bestEffort: true,
                });
            return image.set(stats);
}
```